# Extend UserCreationForm for extended User in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-users

I extended my django user and need to create a registration form now.

I got most of it figured out but I don't know how to exclude fields I don't need during registration. Right know I see all fields in the registration form.

Here is the code:

models.py

```
class Artist(Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    address = CharField(max_length=50)
    city = CharField(max_length=30)
    ustid = CharField(max_length=14)
    date_of_birth = DateField()
    bio = CharField(max_length=500)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()

User.profile = property(lambda u: Artist.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        artist_kwargs = kwargs.copy()
        if kwargs.has_key('instance'):
            self.artist = kwargs['instance'].artist
            artist_kwargs['instance'] = self.artist
        self.artist_form = ArtistForm(*args, **artist_kwargs)
        self.fields.update(self.artist_form.fields)
        self.initial.update(self.artist_form.initial)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(RegistrationForm, self).clean()
        self.errors.update(self.artist_form.errors)
        return cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.artist_form.save(commit)
        return super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit)
```

How do I exclude fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't include or exclude fields that are not a member of the meta model.

What you can do is doing that in each form. In this case the `UserCreationForm` is extended by the `ArtistForm`. Just restrict the fields in the form that belong to the right meta model.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    exclude = ('bio',)
```

Comment: that doesn't work. I can only select fields that belong the the Meta model. But I can select them in my ArtistForm class.